# Location of Operating system in Memory

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system

Galvin says:

> We may place operating system in either low memory or high memory. The major factor affecting this decision is the location of interrupt vector. Since the interrupt vector is usually in low memory, programmers usually place operating system in low memory as well.

I am not quite sure as how the location of interrupt vector affects the location of OS in memory. I tried to google but could not find anything to my satisfaction.
Can someone please clarify this.

Comment: Which memory are you referring to?  Virtual or physical?  I would assume you mean virtual?

Comment: @Jeff :- I am referring to Main memory, hence physical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main memory has primary 2 parts:

1. Resident OS with low memory with interrupt vector, where "An interrupt vector is the memory address of an interrupt handler", i.e. it's one of the lowest levels of memory.
2. User processes in high memory

Now, why is the OS held in low memory?
As you go no high up in the memory, the cost per byte increases and since the OS needs quick access to memory, it should be places lowest in the order.

So, the location of interrupt vector is not the direct reason for operating system to be placed, but it's the the low memory requirement. We know, interrupt vectors will be placed there, so OS is also placed with it.

Comment: - you mean to say access cost per byte increases as we go up in memory ??

Comment: well, from an OS perspective, it does.

Comment: then your answer seems to make sense

Comment: @zengr : can you please clarify more on why the cost per byte increases as we go high up in memory ? is it only access cost or cost in terms of some other parameters also ? can you let me know with some example why access cost or any other cost increases. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the architecture you're talking about, it may be easier/shorter/faster to access addresses that are close to the executed code. So it might be easier for an OS placed in low memory to access the interrupt vector when that is located in low memory.

For example, using x86 in real mode (as opposed to protected mode), if you place the OS into segment 0x0 (where the interrupt vector lives as well) you can refer to the interrupt vectors just using current CS (which would obviously be 0x0) and a 16 bit wide index.

Comment: I'd say, unless your CPU is very slow and/or you have way too little memory (both for the task at hand), it may be more of a convenience than necessity (e.g. you don't want to deal with far pointers and want to avoid writing pointer-related code and using it in many places). Nowadays most nontrivial devices use more than 64KB or so of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Low memory is used for storing memory resident programs as well as programs which use the part of the physical memeory which is not directly mapped by the page tables. And, since Operating Systems fulfill both the criteria, so it is but obvious that it will be stored in the low memory.